# JOptionPane and Graphs

Tags: java, graph, joptionpane

I would like to know how to give JOptionPane the ability to scroll through a histogram. I managed to get JOptionPane to display my histogram, the only problem is you can't scroll through it. The window stretches to the bottom of the screen and displays only half of the graph.

Note: This only happens when reading large input files that contain 300+ integers between 0 and 130. The program will not recognize anything else.

Input Values:

54
38
42
40
34
51
54
58
61
55
54
42
40
34
51
54
54
54
38
60
42
40
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
54
32
28
24
18
9
4
22
31
38
34
41
32
28
24
18
31
38
34
41
32
28
24
18
31
38
34
41
32
28
31
38
35
51
34
41
56
63
59
66
48
46
58
41
56
63
51
59
48
46
58
41
56
63
53
52
58
48
49
58
41
56
63
51
52
59
58
66
63
71
69
70
72
67
66
63
71
74
75
69
73
78
72
67
63
71
74
59
56
69
70
78
72
66
71
74
69
70
78
72
67
63
59
58
57
64
71
72
67
63
59
64
71
73
79
75
78
72
67
63
59
63
71
73
75
78
72
67
63
57
73
77
75
78
72
67
71
73
77
75
78
81
83
87
84
91
92
90
84
76
83
82
89
78
81
83
87
84
91
92
90
84
78
85
82
89
96
91
78
81
83
86
82
91
92
90
84
85
82
89
92
96
91
95
97
98
91
95
97
93
87
85
94
89
92
96
93
96
97
98
98
100
102
95
97
93
87
88
89
93
84
89
92
95
95
95
97
94
91
87
84
80
90
82
80
73
75
70
74
74
75
70
66
63
71
69
70
72
67
66
63
71
55
59
53
58
52
67
63
71
74
59
56
69
70
58
62
56
51
54
49
60
68
62
67
63
59
58
57
64
44
38
42
40
34
51
54
55
54
42
40
34
51
54
54
54
38
42
31
38
34
41
32
28
24
18
31
38
34
41
32
28
24
18
31
38
34
41
32
28
31
28
35
41
34
37
26
23
29
40
45
46
39
31
40
38
29
34
36

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CoolWeather
{
    static JFileChooser selecter;
    static Scanner in;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
       //Get Input File
       File inputFile;
       selecter = new JFileChooser(".");
       int status = selecter.showOpenDialog(null);
       if(status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
       {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Closing Program");
            System.exit(0);
       }
       inputFile = selecter.getSelectedFile();
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Opening: " + inputFile.getName());
       //Creates Array
       int[] temps = readData(inputFile);
       //Prints Histogram
       showMessage(temps);   
    }
    //The Following Method Creates and Populates An Array With Data
    //From The Input File
    public static int[] readData(File inputFile) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
       in = new Scanner(inputFile);
       in.useDelimiter("[^0-9/s]+");
       int[] temps = new int[131];
       int count = 0;
       int num;
       do
       {
           num = in.nextInt();
           count++;
           temps[num]++;
       } 
       while (in.hasNextInt());
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Number Of Entries Read: " + count);
       return temps;    
    }
    public static void showMessage(int[] temps)
    { 
        String output = "Temp\tCount\tVisual";
        // for each array element, output a bar in histogram
        for ( int counter = 0; counter < temps.length; counter++ )
        {
            if (temps[counter] > 0)
            {
            output += "\n" + counter + "\t" + temps[ counter ] + "\t";
            // print bar of asterisks
            for ( int stars = 0; stars < temps[ counter ]; stars++ )
                {output += "*";}
            }
        } // end outer for
        JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();
        outputArea.setText( output );
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, outputArea, "CoolWeather Histogram", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE );
        System.exit( 0 );
    }
}
```

Comment: `JTextArea` must place into `JScrollPane`

Comment: I'm still learning, could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: Look into the `JScrollPane` class and search for tutorials on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the `JOptionPane` I use for UI when handling exceptions, but the principle is the same - `JTextArea` in `JScrollPane`

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ":");
label.setFont(getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
label.setAlignmentX(JLabel.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));

JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setFont(getFont());
textArea.setTabSize(2);
textArea.setText(writer.toString());
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> textArea.setCaretPosition(0));

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
scrollPane.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
panel.add(label);
panel.add(Box.createVerticalStrut(5));
panel.add(scrollPane);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, panel, ApplicationInfo.getAppName(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    JTextArea outputArea = new JTextArea();
    outputArea.setText(output);
    outputArea.setEditable(false);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(outputArea);
    scrollPane.setAlignmentX(JScrollPane.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, scrollPane, "CoolWeather Histogram", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    System.exit( 0 );
```